# Clean Cut Nazir?

Tags: halacha, shaving, nozir

Can a Nazir cut the hairs on his face?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Teshovas Harashba (1:407) says **YES**!!

That is Nazirus is only the Hair on His Head all else is fair game!!

Comment: This, of course, assumes that he leaves alone the hairs in the "five corners" of his beard, which are the subject of a separate mitzvah (Lev. 19:27).

Comment: @Alex Those hairs need giluach and haschata, whereas a nazir's hair would require any cutting to violate the mitzva