# Sidelocks and a Nazarite vow

Tags: shaving, nozir, payot-sideburns

Since it's forbidden to destroy the sidelocks, how does a Nazarite fulfill his vow when shaving upon completion, without violating the prohibition, since the whole head needs to be shaved?

Comment: https://steinsaltz.org/daf/nazir41/ & https://dafyomi.co.il/nazir/discuss/nz-qa-060.4.htm See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2077/27180

Comment: cf https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=5&format=pdf which discusses if a similar case with a metzora is an illustration of the principle that a positive command can (sometimes) override a prohibition.